# Select @@IDENTITY WHERE in Access

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

Trying to get the last ticket ID submitted by the active user in an Access database. This doesn't work unless I leave in "SELECT @@IDENTITY" by itself without the WHERE clause. How can I get it to work with the WHERE clause?

```
        'Pulls the last submitted ticket ID, and makes sure it was submitted by the active user to prevent a race condition scenario among multiple users
    Dim returnvalue As Integer = -1
    Dim custCMD As OleDb.OleDbCommand = New OleDb.OleDbCommand("SELECT @@IDENTITY WHERE [Last Modified By] = '" & Environment.UserName & "';", connection)


    returnvalue = CType(custCMD.ExecuteScalar(), Integer)


    MsgBox(returnvalue)
```

Comment: You cannot use a WHERE clause here. Anyway, what should be its purpose?

Comment: Because of a potential issue if two users are connected to the DB, they both would get the most recent ticket. I would like it to return the most recent ticket ID that the current user submitted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a WHERE clause in the SELECT @@IDENTITY because that command returns the last generated autonumber **for the connection associated with your command**. There is no race condition with other connections running on other pc or on other instance of your own application. Not sure about multiple threads but if you follow best practice to open/use/close the connection then you are on the safe side

Comment: Ok thanks that's what I wanted to make sure of. Basically as long as if multiple users are both running this program and connected to the DB, and they all hit submit at the same time, as long as it returns each ones corresponding ticket ID then all is well.